# Capture Anchor links/route with Node Express and Passport

Tags: node.js, express, single-page-application, passport.js

Many javascript frameworks utilize the anchor tag to establish routing within a SPA.  Is it possible to capture the anchor route to save in my session store while authenticating?

For example, utilizing express and passport, I have:

routes.js

```
//node stuff above
app.get('/', auth.savePath, pages.index);
```

auth.js

```
exports.savePath = function (req, res, next) {
    if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
        req.session.returnPath = req.originalUrl
        return res.redirect('/login')
    }
    next()
}
```

req.originalUrl does not capture the anchor path, only the app path and querystring variables - any thoughts?  I don't see anything else in the express documentation that would let me capture this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hash fragment (what you call anchor) is never sent to the browser, so you can't capture it. Either change your URL scheme to not use hash fragments, or even better: use a client-side library to do the logic on the client-side. Many such libraries exist, usually called "client side routers".

Comment: Yeah, I've use client side routers (it's really the only way to capture navigation in a SPA).  However, I was looking for a way to capture nav info (within the hash fragment) on the server side.  Oh well, thanks for the answer!

Comment: The hash fragment is not sent to the browser automatically, but you can bypass this with a hidden form field. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `app.param` for this explained [here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.param)

The following is some code. The req.params.id captures 'id'.

```
app.param('id', /^\d+$/);
  app.get('/user/:id', function(req, res){
  res.send('user ' + req.params.id);
});
```

Using [Angular-ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), I'm sure you can solve the above purpose:
The

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
 myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

 // Now set up the states
 $stateProvider
  .state('/', {
    url: "/",
    templateUrl: "partials/loginQuestion"
   })
```

The express router would include something like:

```
app.get('/partials/:name', function (req, res) {
    var name = req.params.name;
    console.log(name);
    res.render('partials/' + name);
});
```

Comment: App.param does not capture the hash/anchor fragment.  I'm looking to capture:  /#/user/123456

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the same recently: redirect to a hashed URL after login.  My solution was to capture the hash fragment from document.location.hash and store it in a hidden field in the login form. Then in the passport local-strategy function, I capture it with

```
req.flash('redirectHash' : req.body.myHiddenFieldName).
```

The default redirect after authentication routes to my home page, but in that route I check to see if `req.flash('redirectHash')` is null; if it is not null, I use it to complete my redirect to the desired location.

Have not tested across browsers, but works in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to capture anchor links. Works across all web frameworks.

I'll use an example scenario to illustrate: let's say we need to capture a deep URL http://server.com**/#/xyz** requested by an unauthenticated user so that they can be redirected to that deep URL post-login.

1. The unauthenticated user requests http://server.com**/#/xyz** (everything from the '#' onwards is not sent to the server).
2. All the server knows is that the user wants http://server.com/ and that they are unauthenticated. Server redirects the user to a login form.
3. Here's the clever bit: the client is still waiting on their original request so if the server includes a hidden element in the login form with some JS that references window.location.href, it can capture the full URL **of the original request** complete with the anchor portion:

   ```
   <form action="/login" method="post">
     <div>
       <label>Username:</label>
       <input type="text" name="username"/><br/>
     </div>
     <div>
       <label>Password:</label>
       <input type="password" name="password"/>
     </div>
     <!-- XXXXXXXXX CLEVER BIT XXXXXXXXXX-->
     <script>
       document.write('<input type="hidden" name="from" value="'+document.location.href+'"/>');
     </script>
     <!-- XXXXXXXXXX-->
     <div>
       <input class="submit-button" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
     </div>
   </form>
   ```
4. The user authenticates themself and the original URL is sent with the POST. The server can then relay the user to the original deep URL.